# listView with sound in kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I need to stop the sound if this is playing and click some item

This is my code the part of the setOnItemClickListener:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) var 
    dataItems = DataItems() dataItems.main() val listView = findViewById(R.id.main_listView) var myAdapter = MyAdapter(this, dataItems.lista) 
    listView.adapter = myAdapter

    listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val soundPlay = MediaPlayer.create(this, dataItems.lista.get(position).sound)
        soundPlay.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `soundPlay` a nullable `var` property of the class so you can call `?.stop()` on it in this listener before assigning a new one to the property. And actually, it's good practice to also call `release()` on it to reduce memory and battery usage.

```
private var soundPlay: MediaPlayer? = null

//...

listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
    soundPlay?.apply {
        stop()
        release()
    }
    soundPlay = MediaPlayer.create(this, dataItems.lista.get(position).sound).apply {
        start()
    }
}
```